# how to get all the children of a node as items of an array in javascript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

for example I have the following structure:

```
<div class="parent">  
    <div>1st child</div>  
    <div>2nd child</div>  
    <div>3rd child</div>  
    <div>4th child</div>  
</div>
```

all I want is to have the text of all the children of the parent div as items of an array.
the jQuery solution is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var a = $(".parent").children().map(function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

Comment: Forgot the `.get()` at the end.

Comment: if the parent had other children besides div's this could fail. why not $(".parent div") instead?

Comment: @kobe, map calls the function in its argument for every item in the array. so basically it just calls .text() on each child of the .parent div

Comment: @corroded The asker didn't specify that the children must be divs.

Comment: @emmet, mmm good point. i guess he should have been clearer in his question

Comment: @corroded thanks all, it would be great if it worked with all the other elements not only divs.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_this_text() {
    return $(this).text();
}

$(".parent div").map(get_this_text).get()
```

Here's it on fiddle (see result in your console): http://jsfiddle.net/C6pHS/

Answer (score 1):

Optionally to the other answers could also do this if it helps you to see things more clearly. 
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">  
    <div class="child">1st child</div>  
    <div class="child">2nd child</div>  
    <div class="child">3rd child</div>  
    <div class="child">4th child</div>  
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var childArray = $('.child');
```

Comment: There's no need to add the `child` class to the child `div`s: `$('.parent > div');`

Comment: I know, but as i've said, if it helps him to see more clearly. Just giving alternative answers. Sometimes this help's user's to distinguish the linking between the two.